# Trouble with getting the jQuery to work in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I can't seem to get this working in WordPress no matter what I do. Everything works fine outside of WordPress, but when I put everything in my JS/jQuery will not run. Here is the link where I need it to work [DEMO](http://www.jshuadvd.com/din8/events). Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I have placed my JS/jQuery in the footer.php, in the header.php, everywhere and nothing. Here is the code...

```
         <style type="text/css">
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background: #fff;
    }
    #body-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 180px;
        font-family: Arial;

    }
    .dropMenu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 260px;
        background: #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dropMenu img{
        cursor: pointer;
        padding:20px 20px 10px 20px ;
        float: left;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 30%;
    }
    #event1, #event2, #event3, #event4 {
        margin-bottom: 10px;

    }   
    .left-side {
        float: left;
        margin: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    .SMtext {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 23px;
    }
    #event-day {
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    #event-time{
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;

    }
    #hamburger {
        width: 60px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #ddd;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    #hamburger span {
        background-color: #ddd;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 5px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 9px;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
    #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
        -moz-transform-origin: left center;
        -o-transform-origin: left center;
        transform-origin: left center;
    }
    #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 18px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
        -moz-transform-origin: left center;
        -o-transform-origin: left center;
        transform-origin: left center;
    }
    #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 36px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
        -moz-transform-origin: left center;
        -o-transform-origin: left center;
        transform-origin: left center;
    }
    .open #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        top: -3px;
        left: 8px;
    }
    .open #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 36px;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .open #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        top: 39px;
        left: 8px;
    }
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        display: none;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .content p {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 150%;
        text-align: justify;
        padding: 20px 20px;
    }
    hr {
        width: 96%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 2px;
        color:#bdbdbd;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .details {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: left;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .menu a {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: left;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .right-side{
        float: right;
        margin: 10px 20px;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    .event-price {
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #CD3942;
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    .details-btn {
      -webkit-border-radius: 28;
      -moz-border-radius: 28;
      border-radius: 28px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 20px;
      background: #A4C739;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-top: 115px;

    }
    .details-btn:hover {
      background: #222;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .event-order-btn {
      -webkit-border-radius: 28;
      -moz-border-radius: 28;
      border-radius: 28px;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 20px;
      background: #A4C739;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      float: right;
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }
    .event-order-btn:hover {
      background: #222;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

</style>



<div id="event-container">


<div id="body-container">
<div id="event1">
  <div class="dropMenu" onClick="ToggleIt(this)">
    <img src="http://www.jshuadvd.com/din8/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/event4.jpg" />

    <div class="left-side">
    <div class="SMtext">RESTAURANT NAME</div><br />
    <div id="event-day"><i class="icon-circle-calendar">  SATURDAY, DECEMBER 20, 2014</i></div><br />
    <div id="event-time"><i class="icon-circle-clock"></i>  7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-side">
    <div class="event-price">$ 90</div>     
    <div class="details-btn">VIEW DETAILS</div>
    </div>

    <div id="hamburger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="content1">
  <hr>
  <div class="details">EVENT DETAILS</div>
  <br />
  <br />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?      
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">MENU</a>      
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="" class="event-order-btn">I WANT TO DINATE</a>
      </div>
      <br />    
    </p>  
  </div>
  </div>


<div id="event2">
  <div class="dropMenu" onClick="ToggleIt(this)">
    <img src="http://www.jshuadvd.com/din8/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/event11.jpg" />

    <div class="left-side">
    <div class="SMtext">RESTAURANT NAME</div><br />
    <div id="event-day"><i class="icon-circle-calendar">  SATURDAY, DECEMBER 20, 2014</i></div><br />
    <div id="event-time"><i class="icon-circle-clock"></i>  7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-side">
    <div class="event-price">$ 90</div>     
    <div class="details-btn">VIEW DETAILS</div>
    </div>

    <div id="hamburger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="content1">
  <hr>
  <div class="details">EVENT DETAILS</div>
  <br />
  <br />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?      
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">MENU</a>      
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="" class="event-order-btn">I WANT TO DINATE</a>
      </div>
      <br />    
    </p>  
  </div>
  </div>



  <div id="event3">
  <div class="dropMenu" onClick="ToggleIt(this)">
    <img src="http://www.jshuadvd.com/din8/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/event21.jpg" />

    <div class="left-side">
    <div class="SMtext">RESTAURANT NAME</div><br />
    <div id="event-day"><i class="icon-circle-calendar">  SATURDAY, DECEMBER 20, 2014</i></div><br />
    <div id="event-time"><i class="icon-circle-clock"></i>  7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-side">
    <div class="event-price">$ 90</div>     
    <div class="details-btn">VIEW DETAILS</div>
    </div>

    <div id="hamburger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="content1">
  <hr>
  <div class="details">
  EVENT DETAILS
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?      
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">MENU</a>      
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="" class="event-order-btn">I WANT TO DINATE</a>
      </div>
      <br />    
    </p>  
  </div>
  </div>



  <div id="event4">
  <div class="dropMenu" onClick="ToggleIt(this)">
    <img src="http://www.jshuadvd.com/din8/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/event31.jpg" />

    <div class="left-side">
    <div class="SMtext">RESTAURANT NAME</div><br />
    <div id="event-day"><i class="icon-circle-calendar">  SATURDAY, DECEMBER 20, 2014</i></div><br />
    <div id="event-time"><i class="icon-circle-clock"></i>  7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-side">
    <div class="event-price">$ 90</div>     
    <div class="details-btn">VIEW DETAILS</div>
    </div>

    <div id="hamburger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="content1">
  <hr>
  <div class="details">
  EVENT DETAILS
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
      <br />
      <br />
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?      
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">MENU</a>      
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="" class="event-order-btn">I WANT TO DINATE</a>
      </div>
      <br />    
    </p>  
  </div>
  </div>


</div>

</body>

<!------------ Begin JavaScript ------>

<script type='text/javascript'> 

function ToggleIt(elem) {
  $(elem).toggleClass('open').next().slideToggle();
}


</script>

<!------------ End JavaScript ---------->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your `functions.php` in your theme directory add the following:

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_register_script('my_script', home_url() . '/wp-content/themes/mythemename/js/jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script');
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

after change the `$` to `jQuery` in your page:

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    function ToggleIt(elem) {
        jQuery(elem).toggleClass('open').next().slideToggle();
    }
</script>
```

The best way to add jquery is in your `functions.php` file.

change only
/wp-content/themes/mythemename/js/jquery.js   //path to your jquery script as you mention event.js

Comment: why this downvote this is the correct way to add jquery

Comment: Ok thanks, should I also change "my_script" to the name of the file say if I name it event.js?

Comment: you only change  wp_register_script('my_script', home_url() . '/wp-content/themes/mythemename/js/jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ));

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! Worked like a charm! I would love to upvote you, but I don't have enough rep yet... :( Sorry!

Comment: @jshuadvd - You should accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

change the `$` to `jQuery`

```
function ToggleIt(elem) {
    jQuery(elem).toggleClass('open').next().slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: Ok great. Then where should I place the code? Do I need to initialize it somehow?